# how to do a select on like values from multiple columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like

I have two tables with columns:

```
Genres  
  ID  
  genre
```

and

```
Adjectives
  ID
  adjective_title
```

I need to do a select that returns the matching values from both tables columns with the `like` syntax.

For example if **ep** was the value entered using `like` the results would look like:

```
result_column:
--------------
epiphonic -- (from genres table)
epic      -- (from adjectives table)
```

etc . . .

I'm pretty sure I need to use a subquery to return the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT genre AS result
FROM genres
WHERE genre LIKE '%ep%'
UNION
SELECT adjective_title AS result
FROM 
  adjectives
WHERE adjective_title LIKE '%ep%'
```

The union will eliminate duplicates in each query use UNION ALL for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without sub-selects, but it won't be quick on large tables, by using concat to build the string you use the like operator on:

```
select g.ID, g.genre, a.adjective_title from Genres g, Adjectives a where
concat(g.genre, a.adjective_title) like '%epic%'
```